# Multi step form - ajax response on the following step

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

is it possible in case of multisteps form (php -ajax - jquery) to get the response from step1 on step 2.
For the moment, I get the response but it's block the process form and it's noted on phase1 form.
Precision : I'm beginner whith ajax and jquery.

```
success : function(data){
if (data != 'passed') {
    jQuery('#messages-errors').html(data);
}  
if (data == 'passed') {

    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#step2").show("slow");
    $(".open1").css("display","none");
    $(".open2").css("display","inline-block");

    $("#check-ok").html(data);
 }
 },
 error : function(){
    alert('no working.'); }
 });
 }
 });
```

Comment: You can use sessions to store data between pages or 'steps'

Comment: What is the `data` variable supposed to hold? Should it really be just a string `passed` ?

Comment: not working too cause I need to reload my page -->  my form is on a modal

Comment: @Dainis Abols - I just need to pass three variables. Two in string and one to put inside input hidden on phase2

Comment: Is the next step on the same page or does the page get reloaded? If its on the same page, then use JS to set the variables.If it gets reloaded, then there is no need for ajax in the first place.

Comment: @Dainis Abols it's the same page  same form Inside a modal but #step2 - I've tried to use sessions and then my page need to be reload  cause it's a modal I think

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to prepare a blank input field (or multiple ones) in the next step and populate them after successful ajax call similar to this: `$('#input_field').val(data.value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make as many ajax calls as you want in a page.So if you want different data in every step you can just make another ajax call.If the problem is that you want multiple data returned, you can just return a json object from your php file, for example :

```
                 $data['success'] = true;
                 $data['string1'] = 'a string';
                 $data['string2'] = 'second string';

                 echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in your ajax callback function you just access the returned object.For example

```
             success : function(data){    
                 if (data.success) {
                 alert(data.string1);
                 }
                }
```

You can then do whatever you want with your data,save your data in global javascript variables (or hidden input fields as suggested in the comments) if you want so you can access them easily from other parts of your javascript etc.

Comment: Thanks to for answers. It's stop all my process message errors

Comment: No .... it block the process errors. But as I said I'm beginner perhars errors on placement code. but thanks to answer   it's very kind of you.

Comment: javascript errors?php errors? you have to be more specific and show your code so we can help you

Comment: WORKING many many many thanks. Just take time to understand how it's work..

Comment: Happy my answer helped you.If you found it useful please accept or upvote.Thanks

Comment: Evkaristo para poli .... kai an eivai mono data pou selo na valo se input hidden ma always in pase 2?